# having case block in where clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, procedure

in my procedure I am trying to incorporate a case block to perform a conditional check in where clause. could you please help here.

below is my procedure body which is working fine..

```
FROM  TABLE_A
WHERE  name = p_name
AND address = p_address
AND state = p_state
AND ((p_county IS NULL AND default_zone = 'Y') OR (county = p_county)) ;
```

now I would like to split the last segment.
I will always get a county column, so as standard way, below block will work and this is must to have in code(this logic)

```
WHERE name = p_name
AND address = p_address
AND state = p_state
AND county = p_county
```

now suppose, county which we got during procedure call is not available, so in this case DB will not return any data,, a "NO_DATA_FOUND" error will come. now if this error come, I have to execute below block..

```
WHERE  name = p_name
AND address = p_address
AND state = p_state
AND default_zone = 'Y'
```

Simplest way, I should use the procedure twice and make call of second block on exception but this may procedure very bulky and does not look good also..is there a way it can be written in simpler way..

I am trying to use case block to have this code but its not working for me.. pls advice

Comment: What is the issue you are trying to solve?  Your original code looks fine.  And, what do you mean by "case block"? (I only understand the concept in terms of Oracle PL/SQL but neither your tags nor code necessarily suggest Oracle.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff  sorry for confusion.. I have edit my post now. please check and help me on this.

Comment: So, is this Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or what?

Comment: could someone please suggest me a simple option to have it implemented..

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you'd want to rewrite to `case`, but one solution would be:

```
WHERE   CASE 
        WHEN p_county IS NULL AND default_zone = 'Y' THEN county
        ELSE p_county
        END = county
```

I personally think your original `OR` query is clearer.

---

In response to your comment: you could use `dense_rank` to split the table in default and non-default parts.  With `order by default_zone`, you give the non-default priority, as `N` comes before `Y` in the alphabet.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  dense_rank() over (
                    order by default_zone) rn
        ,       name
        ,       state
        ,       county
        ,       default_zone
        from    YourTable
        where   county = p_county
                or default_zone = 'Y'
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Pick matching county, or else default
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed3b0/10/1)

Comment: Sorry for confusion.. I have edit my post with more clear description. Please check and advise.

Comment: I am not able to incorporate this code in my code. could you pleases suggest some other simple option.